# Cauchy sequence but not essentially bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, sobolev-spaces

I have trouble understanding how can a sequence $\{u_k\} \in C^1{(\mathbb{U})}$, with $\mathbb{U} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ bounded and $\|u_k\|_{H_1(\mathbb{U})} < \infty$, can be Cauchy with respect to the $H^1$ norm but **not** be essentially bounded.

Doesn't essentially unbounded mean that it diverges in non-zero measure set? Could you provide me any ideas/hints to construct such a sequence in the 2D unit disk?

Comment: It means there is no single bound that holds a.e. In 3D or higher an example of an unbounded $H^1$ function (i.e. a possible limit for a sequence like in your question) is $\log(\|x\|)$ on the ball centered at the origin. Where this question is most interesting is in 2D, where the relevant Sobolev conjugate is infinity but $H^1$ still fails to embed into $L^\infty$.

Comment: @Ian I have updated the question because the problem I am working on is indeed for 2D. My question remains, even for $n > 2$, what I don't get is how the norm $\int_{\mathbb{U}} |\nabla u_k|^2 + |u_k|^2 \to 0$ for $k\to\infty$ even though the singularity is not on an isolated point.

Comment: @Ian Ok, I think I have misinterpreted the definition, it is actually $\|u_{k+1}-u_{k}\|_{H^1} \to 0$ that I need to ensure, right? Thus I just need to construct a sequence with logarithmic singularity and bounded $H^1$ norms.

Comment: No, you need it to actually be Cauchy in $H^1$, which means you will probably want to start by finding something in $H^1$ but not $L^\infty$. There is a classic way to do this with logs but it isn't quite what I said for 3D (which would result in a non-$L^2$ gradient).

Comment: Ok, I have constructed a sequence using a $\log\log(\alpha/r)$ radial function with $\alpha > 1$, say $\alpha =2$ to avoid singularity of gradient. Then I have shown that the $H^1$ norm is bounded in $\mathbb{U}$. Also, $\|\cdot\|_{H^1}$ is non-decreasing. But how do I express this in terms of $\|u_j-u_k\|_{H^1} \to 0$ as $j,k\to\infty$?

Comment: Just pick an approximation of it, such as a mollification of it.